# What is the best way or best practice to check that jQuery has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to check that jQuery has been loaded, I've found different approaches for that and wanted to see their differences, also to know which one may be better or would be best practice to use.

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    // jQuery has been loaded.
}

if (window.jQuery){
    // jQuery has been loaded.
}
```

This one is the same as previous example but using `window.onload`, what's their difference at the run time?

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        // jQuery has been loaded.
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way is to not use jQuery most likely. Otherwise - script loading is synchronous, if you have a script tag pointing at jQuery and a script tag afterwards (and neither are async or defer) - you can rely on jQuery being loaded in the next script tag and not check for it. If you put both at the end of the body tag - you also don't need to do stuff like `jQuery(...)` (or $.ready...) - simply include jQuery via a script tag and then use it.

Comment: Also - for what it's worth the web has largely moved to modules and web bundles - so the thing "requiring" jQuery is your code with an `import * as jQuery from 'jquery'` inside your other files - with webpack taking care of config or `import('...').then(jQuery => ` with a dynamic module load.

Comment: if you wanna use code after jquery ready  may you can use it `$(document).ready(fucntion(){//here your code});`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for you help and guides, I want to know the difference between those 3 code snippets above.

Comment: @GilangPratama I want to check that the jQuery is available or not, I've found those 3 approaches, I wanted to see their differences  at run time or the logic behind how they would run.

Comment: #1 and #2 are mostly identical for what you're doing. #3 also waits for all images and scripts to load before performing the check and is significantly slower. You shouldn't use any of them and just place jQuery close to the end of the body.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks so much, I'm trying to write a module so that I would be able to make a jQuery plugin, so being jQuery available is a priority(the quick way). In the future I would add the vanilla javascript way to the module.

Comment: You may assume jQuery is loaded when building a jQuery plugin you shouldn't check for it - it's up to whomever is adding your code.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Great, thanks so much for your help and knowledge sharing.